# adb, how to get the view of the pop-up message?

Tags: android, popup, adb, dump, android-uiautomator

dear all:

I am an old professor taking over my students' legacy program that crawls an Android app screen activities. 
The program uses the following standard command to download the screen activity in XML from uiautomator.

os.system("adb -s "+sn+" shell /system/bin/uiautomator dump /sdcard/uidump.xml")

The screen shows a list of files and folders in a folder.
When I click a document, it pops up a view that shows a list of actions, including changing the names of the clicked item.
Then I click the change-name item and the Android device screen shows a text input field for the new item name.

However, when I used the above os.system command, uiautomator always dumped the main screen activity behind the pop-up views.
Is there a way to request uiautomator to dump the XML of the pop-up view ?

Thanks

Comment: `uiautomator` depends on the `accessibility service` to obtain the information. As long as the application is properly configured in that regard - there is no distinction between *main screen* and *pop-up views*

Comment: Hi, dear Alex!  Thanks for the reply.  Did you mean that perhaps the app is not properly configured ?

Comment: I guess you are getting the screen dump in python, then you can take a look at [AndroidViewClient/culebra](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) which will make your life much easier.

Comment: Have you tried to view the same using `uiautomatorviewer` ? you can find it in /sdk/tools/ folder. if you can see the ui layout of the popup in viewer, you should get the same in dump command also. Yes as you are doing this from python culebra is a good option  because it is in python.

Comment: Thank you!  Since we are developing a crawler for the app, we need use API to know if the elements are active or not.